# Invalid and/or missing SSL certificate when using Google gdata library in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl-certificate, gdata, urlfetch

I am implementing a back-end on GAE which uses `gdata.apps.audit.service.AuditService.createMailboxExportRequest` to make mailbox export request to Google. 
I have copied the `gdata` lib into my app directory. My code works normally in local Python 2.7
However it raise an error like this when I run the code in GoogleAppEngine Develop environment:

> INFO     2014-05-26 08:05:21,793 discovery.py:190] URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/admin/directory_v1/rest?userIp=0.1.0.2
>
> INFO     2014-05-26 08:05:21,794 client.py:474] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
>   INFO     2014-05-26 08:05:21,807 client.py:680] Refreshing access_token

AuditService is created and ok!

Error is next:

> WARNING  2014-05-26 08:05:24,633 urlfetch_stub.py:482] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Host', 'Content-Length']
>
> Invalid and/or missing SSL certificate for URL: https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/mail/export/mydomainhere.com/barney

Please give me an explanation why I can not run this on GAE!
It exactly raise error while running `createMailboxExportRequest` and maybe related to Google `urlfetch_stub`. I am so confused.

UPDATE : I changed to using `httplib2` to make request directly to Google API without using their `gdata` library and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution found by the original poster was to switch to the Python’s `httplib2` library to address requests directly to the Google API.

According to the original issue, it is possible that the failure to validate the certificate resulted from a network error when fetching the certificate. This could have been the explanation if the error only occurred one time.